# how to write a Python script for public use that uses passcodes internally

Tags: python, security, passwords

I have a Python script that accesses the API of a web service. In order to access this API, it uses some passcodes. At present, these are stored as plain text strings in the Python script. I want to make the actions of this script executable by others but these others should not be able to see the passcodes. They should solely be able to execute the script and pass to it some arguments when doing so.

My first, very basic, attempt at making it a little secure has been to compile the script:

```
python -m py_compile test.py
```

At this point, the compiled version of the script is executable in the following way:

```
python test.pyc
```

What should I do next to make this more secure?

Comment: give each user a passcode cause there is no way to hide the passcode 100%.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This can be another feature certainly, but I'm talking about API passcodes used internally and not on a per-user basis. I know that the security is unlikely to be perfect, but I'm wondering if there is a better approach than the simple one I'm using currently.

Comment: You could use encryption (ex. don't keep the passcode in plain text but keep it base64 encoded and decode it from the code) but the decription mechanism will be in your code so it won't be hard to reverse engineer it. You could also use a tool to obfuscate the code. Make sure the server is https otherwise the passcode will be sent in plain text and anyone sniffing packages will be able to see it. Not a whole lot you can do really.

Comment: Require users of your script to provide their own API keys?

Comment: Write your script so that instead of using the passcode to access the API directly, it actually talks to a proxy (using whatever security you want) that talks to the real API for it. On a related note, you may need to consider the terms under which you received the passcode for the service.